# R: calculating demand and supply dynamics

Tags: r

A sample data first

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(day= 1:50 ,demand = sample(0:17, size = 50,replace = T),supply = sample(2:9, size = 50,replace = T))
reservoir <- 200
```

I have a data of demand and supply starting with day 1 till 50
and a fourth column which is the difference between supply and demand

```
dat$balance <- dat$supply - dat$demand
```

I want to calculate another column called `net deficit`. Here's the logic

If for a given day, Demand > Supply, a deficit exists. However, this 
deficit can be met by `reservoir` and hence the `net deficit` columns will get zero,

If Supply > Demand, the excess supply is either added to reservoir (only if reservoir < 200).If reservoir is at its full capacity (200), the excess supply is discarded

If Demand > Supply and reservoir is zero, then the `net deficit` column gets the difference between Demand and Supply

For example, starting with day 1, there was a deficit (`balance`) of 3. This deficit is met by reservoir (making it 197) and, `net deficit` is zero,

Day 2: deficit is -9 which is borrowed from reservoir (making it 188) and `net defict` will be zero again.

Day 3, there is an excess of 1 which is used to fill reservoir (since reservoir < 100) `net deficit` gets a value of 0 and reservour becomes (189)

Day 4: there is a deficit of 13 in balance which is met by reservoir. Reservoir further reduces to 176

I hope this is clear.

If at some point of time, reservoir becomes 0, deficit cannot be compensated and 
therefore `net deficit` gets the value of `dat$balance`

Comment: Okay. Is that this simple :(

Comment: I do not have a `deficit` column. Did you mean `200 + cumsum(dat$balance)`

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I meant: `reservoir + cumsum(dat$balance)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is basically using a `for` loop to construct the `reservoir` vector based on the balance each day. The provided sample did not actually manage to empty the reservoir in 50 days, so I made it longer (but this means the numbers are not the same as the 50 day example). You can then simply bind the vector as a column to your data, and set the `net_deficit` column to zero while `reservoir` is positive.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
dat <- tibble(
  day = 1:100,
  demand = sample(0:17, size = 100,replace = T),
  supply = sample(2:9, size = 100,replace = T)
  )

balance <- dat$supply - dat$demand
reservoir <-  rep(200, nrow(dat))
reservoir[1] <- reservoir[1] + balance[1]
for (day in 2:nrow(dat)){
  reservoir[day] <- reservoir[day - 1] + balance[day]
}

out <- dat %>%
  bind_cols(balance =  balance, reservoir = reservoir) %>%
  mutate(net_deficit = ifelse(reservoir >= 0, 0, reservoir))
out[61:70, ]
# A tibble: 10 x 6
     day demand supply balance reservoir net_deficit
   <int>  <int>  <int>   <int>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1    61     11      6     - 5      3.00        0   
 2    62      1      4       3      6.00        0   
 3    63      6      7       1      7.00        0   
 4    64      4      4       0      7.00        0   
 5    65     14      4     -10    - 3.00      - 3.00
 6    66      8      6     - 2    - 5.00      - 5.00
 7    67     14      7     - 7    -12.0       -12.0 
 8    68     14      3     -11    -23.0       -23.0 
 9    69     14      5     - 9    -32.0       -32.0 
10    70      7      4     - 3    -35.0       -35.0
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I wondered which part of the code takes care of the fact that the reservoir on a particular day cannot go beyond 200.

Comment: Does this address it: `for(day in 2:nrow(dat)) {reservoir[day] <- reservoir[day - 1] + balance[day]; reservoir[day] <- ifelse(reservoir[day] > 200, 200, reservoir[day])
}`